# Rebus thread safe

Tags: c#, rebus

I'm trying to find documentation about Rebus and thread safety.
Specifically I'm using a Rebus to pub/sub on the local msmqueue.
One application will be publishing with the Bus and want to make sure this will work, I'm creating tests to replicate a heavy loaded scenario, but want to know if someone already had to deal with this.

Comment: I'd expect it to be - this is the lighest scenario: only one publisher, multiple subscribers. And MSMQ is a separate service, it doesn't care whether messages are coming from one or many applications/threads. In fact, I'm not sure how thread-safety is relevant in this case, unless you are reusing ReBus classes between threads

Comment: The pub is multrithreaded using the same bus, that's my case.
I didn't go through the implementation of the bus, but I saw in MSDN documentation that the msmq client that pushes messages is not thread safe

Comment: Why do you assume that ReBus uses a single client instance for *its* worker threads?

Comment: As mentioned, I didn't find any documentation on this, and didn't dig into the code. I know the author of Rebus is actively supporting and helping here, hence my question that was not only answered but a new page to the wiki was added. Thanks @mookid8000

Answer (score 1):

I realize that I haven't written so much about this subject on the wiki, so [I have added a page about it just now](https://github.com/rebus-org/Rebus/wiki/Thread-safety-and-instance-policies) - I hope that covers the your general concerns about thread safety.

Regarding the use of MSMQ, I took care to use the right overload of the MSMQ `Send` method :) the one that accepts MSMQ's `Message` object is NOT subject to the race condition described [in this blog post](https://yoelarnon.wordpress.com/2008/10/04/meet-you-in-pdc-2008-usa-visit-is-send-thread-safe/).